# Variable outside of function, tried RegEx but can't seem to make it work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, function, dom

I have a function which should remove the number at the end of a class and replace it with a random one. But I have to declare a variable before the function to make it work. It is just a random number between 0 and 9 and I'm trying to find a method to do it without declaring the variable

I tried this which works:

```
 let p
  function onRandomize(t = gsap.utils.random(0, 9, 1)) {
    document.querySelector('.home').classList.remove(`home--${p}`);
    p = t;
    document.querySelector('.home').classList.add(`home--${t}`);
  }
```

My problem is, I don't like having a variable declared outside the element, as in `p` is just any number between 0 and 9. I tried declaring `p` as `const rg = /[0-9]/` and doing `'home--' + rg` but it doesn't do anything.
I don't think it is that hard but I can't grasp the concept around it.

Thank you

Comment: The `classList.remove` method has no wildcard or regex abilities. You give it *the name* of the class you want to remove and it does that, period. So if you don't know the name of the class, the next best thing for you to do is to loop over the class list to test the name yourself (i.e. test which class name starts with "home--" for example). — The better method would probably be to think of something that doesn't require switching numbered classes like this…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using template literals `${}` can contain js code,

```
let home = document.querySelector('.home');
home.classList.add(`home--${gsap.utils.random(0, 9, 1)}`);
//or normal string concatination
home.classList.add("home--"+gsap.utils.random(0, 9, 1));
```

As for removing the random classname that you would need to loop over the `classList` until you find your classname and then remove it:

```
for(let className of home.classList){
   if(className.startsWith('home--')){
      home.classList.remove(className);
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for regex here. Simplify to `className.includes('home--')` or `className.startsWith('home--')`. If a strict match is desired, the regex should have anchors: `/^home--\d$/`.

Comment: @InSync, true, mind was just stuck on regex for some reason, updated.